# JSON error "Value at result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" in android

Tags: android, json, json-rpc

I used the [link](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/) for JSON RPC. I am getting a response as expected. But when i try to parse the response, it's giving me json error.

My code:

```
JSONEntity entity = new JSONEntity(jsonRequest);
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.150/jsondemo12/service.asmx");
    request.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream content = httpEntity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        content.close();
    } else {
        Log.e(AndroidJSONActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
    }


    strJSONValue=builder.toString();

    txtViewParsedValue.append("\n+++++++++++++\n"+strJSONValue+"\n");
    try {
        parseJSON();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("error","Error while parsing!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("response", strJSONValue);
public void parseJSON() throws JSONException
    {
        String attr1="",attr2="";
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(strJSONValue);
        JSONArray  result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");    <- Error in this line!!!
        for(int i=0;i < result.length();i++){
            JSONObject e = result.getJSONObject(i);
            attr1 = "ExhibitorID: "+ e.getString("ExhibitorID");
            attr2 = "ExhibitorName: "+e.getString("ExhibitorName");
        }
        strParsedValue=attr1+"\n"+attr2;
        Log.d("Parse", attr1);
        Log.d("Parse", attr2);

        txtViewParsedValue.append("\n**********\nParsed Value: \n");
        txtViewParsedValue.append(strParsedValue);
    }
```

The result i get in "strJSONValue" is string format, without the starting and ending double quotes. 
Like:

```
{"id":2,"result":"[
{\"ExhibitorID\":42, etc....}
]"}
```

The result string is as per requirement,but i am not able to parse the string into the JSON Object as per requirement. It gives error in Logcat: `org.json.JSONException: Value <content of the string> at result of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your result is actually returning a string not a json array. it will return json array if your json format would be like this

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "result": [
    {
      "ExhibitorID": 42
    }
  ]
}
```

currently it is in this form:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "result": "[ {\"ExhibitorID\":42, etc....} ]"
}
```

Comment: Send me your cv on my id.there is an opening for an android dev in interrait

Comment: so, i need to alter the string received then pass it ahead for parsing?

Comment: I think , In webservice when you are creating json array , you are converting it into string. don't convert it. changing received response is not a good habit.well For solution, you can take "result tag" in string first using getString and then covert the string in json object using  new JSONObject(string); and after that parse it.

Comment: how do i take the result tag ?